# MySQL table ranking ranks the first row as 0 instead of 1

Tags: mysql, function, count, increment, ranking

I'm having trouble with ranking the records in my table. It seems to be handling ties correctly, but for some reason the first row is being ranked as a zero, so the order I'm getting is coming out like 0, 2, 2, 4, 5. I've been playing about with this for ages and I've had no luck and I've been all over Google. I have a feeling I'm missing something really simple and obvious but I'll be damned if I can spot it.

Any help would be appreciated

```
<?php
$year = "$_POST[year]";
$gender = "$_POST[gender]";
$age = "$_POST[age]";
$event = "$_POST[event]";

// Formulate Query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT(athletes.firstname,' ',athletes.lastname) AS athletename, athletes.athleteid, events.eventname, events.eventcode, meetings.meetingid, meetings.meetingname, meetings.location, meetings.meetingdate, meetings.year, DATE_FORMAT(meetings.meetingdate,'%%d %%b %%Y') AS date, results.performance, results.unit, results.eventid, results.position, results.heat, results.wind, agegroups.agegroupid, agegroups.agegroup 
FROM results 
JOIN athletes ON athletes.athleteid = results.athleteid
JOIN meetings ON meetings.meetingid = results.meetingid
JOIN events ON events.eventid = results.eventid
JOIN agegroups ON agegroups.agegroupid = results.agegroupid
WHERE results.performance = ANY (SELECT MAX(results.performance) from results WHERE meetings.year LIKE '%s' AND athletes.gender LIKE '%s' AND agegroups.agegroup LIKE '%s' AND results.eventid='%s' AND meetings.indoors='no' AND events.eventtype='field' GROUP BY results.athleteid)
ORDER BY results.performance desc, meetings.meetingdate asc) t1
GROUP BY t1.athleteid ORDER BY performance desc",
mysql_real_escape_string($year),
mysql_real_escape_string($gender),
mysql_real_escape_string($age),
mysql_real_escape_string($event));

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Check result
if (!$result) {
$message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
$message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
die($message);
}

// Use result
$rank = 0; $prevScore = 0; $naive_rank = 0; $aware_rank = 0; while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {     
$naive_rank++; // always increment
if ($prevScore > $row['performance']) {
//whenever a non-tie occurs the aware rank catches up
$aware_rank = $naive_rank;
$rank = $naive_rank;
} else {
//whenever a tie occurs, just use the old aware rank
$rank = $aware_rank;
} 
$prevScore = $row['performance'];   
echo "<table valign='top' border='0' width='100%'>";
echo "<tr><td width='5%'> $rank </td>";
echo "<td width='20%'> <a href='profile.php?id=$row[athleteid]'> $row[athletename] </a> </td>";
echo "<td width='5%' align='right'> $row[performance] </td>";
echo "<td width='5%' align='left'> $row[unit] </td>";
echo "<td width='5%'> $row[wind] </td>";
echo "<td width='5%'> $row[position] </td>";
echo "<td width='5%'> $row[heat] </td>";
echo "<td width='5%'> $row[agegroup] </td>";
echo "<td width='30%'> <a href='meeting.php?id=$row[meetingid]'> $row[meetingname] </a></td>";
echo "<td width='15%' align='right'> $row[date] </td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

// Free the resources associated with the result set
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

**EDIT**

The table that is currently being displayed:

```
| # | Name      | Perf. | Pos. | Age | Meeting   | Location | Date |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | Athlete A | 18.89 | 1    | U17 | Meeting A | Location | Date |
| 2 | Athlete B | 17.99 | 3    | U20 | Meeting C | Location | Date |
| 2 | Athlete C | 17.99 | 2    | V50 | Meeting F | Location | Date |
| 4 | Athlete D | 15.66 | 1    | U23 | Meeting H | Location | Date |
| 5 | Athlete E | 12.43 | 4    | U15 | Meeting B | Location | Date |
```

Comment: Can you show us a bit of data regarding the expected results? I have this feeling that usually, when the second and third participants to finish are tied, what actually happens in sports is that you get a #1, then two #2, one #4, etc, right? That's not what seems to be happening here?

Comment: I've edited my question to show what I'm currently receiving. What I expect to receive if it works correctly is that the 0 would actually be a 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you initialise `$prevScore` to 0, so for the very first athlete, `$prevScore > $row['performance']` is false, and so `$rank = $aware_rank`, which starts at 0. At this point `$naive_rank` is 1.

Then for athlete number 2, `$naive_rank` is 2 so you get the jump.

You can either:

- initialise `$prevScore` to infinity (ie some huge number, so that for the first athlete `$prevScore > $row['performance']` so that `$aware_rank` and `$rank` are set to 1 (instead of 0)); **OR**
- initialise `$aware_rank` to 1 so that athelete 1 gets `$rank = $aware_rank` (since for the first athlete, `$prevScore > $row['performance']` will never be true if the performance is always >= 0, since `$prevScore` is 0).

Comment: I'm pulling my hair out here, I've just changed $aware_rank to 1 and it's worked. I did this earlier and it displayed every rank as a 1 (i.e. 1, 1, 1, 1, 1). Thanks for explaining the initialisation though, I've been teaching myself MySQL and some of it isn't always clear until someone else explains it.

Comment: In your case the MySQL was perfect - the problem was only on the PHP side.